# SQL Join with MAX().

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables, users and contestants. I'm trying to select the max contestant ID that has a profile picture(which is on the user table)

Heres my terrible SQL:

```
SELECT u.thumbnail, u.id FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT c.id, c.user_id FROM contestants AS c
 WHERE u.id = c.users_id
AND c.id = (select max(c.id))
) WHERE u.thumbnail IS NOT NULL
```

The error currently is: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.

This confuses me since Users has an alias of u, and contestants has an alias of c..

What am I doing wrong here? I'm guessing a lot so some help would be really appreciated!

Comment: exactly! ***" #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"***.  Give  an Alias to the second table (inner join one) like you did for first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are performing a join operation, you are actually joining two table. The subquery you wrote here, for instance, is working as a separate table. Hence, you have to use an alias to this table. That's the reason behind your error message.

Your query:

```
    SELECT u.thumbnail, u.id FROM users AS u
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT c.id, c.user_id FROM contestants AS c
    WHERE u.id = c.users_id
    AND c.id = (select max(c.id))
    ) WHERE u.thumbnail IS NOT NULL
```

It should contain an alias for the subquery:

```
    SELECT c.id, c.user_id FROM contestants AS c
    WHERE u.id = c.users_id
    AND c.id = (select max(c.id))
```

Let's say, it's T.

So, your query now becomes:

```
    SELECT u.thumbnail, u.id FROM users AS u
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT c.id, c.user_id FROM contestants AS c
    WHERE u.id = c.users_id
    AND c.id = (select max(c.id)) 
    ) AS T
    WHERE u.thumbnail IS NOT NULL
```

But what you are trying to achieve, can actually be done in a neater way:

```
    SELECT u.thumbnail, u.id, max(c.id),
    FROM users as u
    LEFT JOIN contestants as c
    on u.id = c.user_id
    WHERE u.thumbnail IS NOT NULL
```

Why make all the fuss when you have a better and neater approach at your disposal?

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I could give you more up votes because my problem is solved and you've explained sub queries to me which I was pretty vague on to begin with! Awesome answer! :D

Comment: So kind of you @Sean. I'm happy to see that my answer helped you, that's all. :) About subqueries, basically I am also a beginner, and I only recently started learning about subqueries. That's why I was able to identify your problem as I've learned it fresh. Learning is a continuous process. Keep learning, keep solving problems, and you'll eventually find yourself at a better position.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT u.thumbnail, u.id 
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT c.id, c.user_id FROM contestants AS c
 WHERE u.id = c.users_id
 AND c.id = (select max(c.id))
)A 
WHERE u.thumbnail IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'u.id' in 'where clause'

Thanks for the fast response, what exactly is that A about after the ) ?

Comment: Would the fact that I have many more contestants than users be messing this up? Should I be selecting from contestants first and then joining users or does it matter? o.O

Comment: the problem is you should not mention the `u.id` is name of u in here  `WHERE u.id = c.users_id`. and the `A` means just `alias` name only..

Comment: Okay, how can I refer to them then? I've tried WHERE users.id = c.users_id, WHERE id = c.users_id and even WHERE A.id = c.users_id for the laugh and same error pretty much. ;(

Answer (score 0):

i think this should be simple,

```
SELECT  u.thumbnail, u.id
FROM    users u
        INNER JOIN contestants c
            ON u.id = c.users_id
WHERE   u.thumbnail IS NOT NULL
ORDER   BY c.id DESC
LIMIT   1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.

```
SELECT  user.thumbnail, user.id
FROM    users user
        INNER JOIN contestants cont ON cont.id = cont.users_id
WHERE   cont.thumbnail IS NOT NULL
ORDER   BY user.id DESC
```